# Change Spark Dataframe Array[String] to Array[Double]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new to scala and I have the following issue.

I have a spark dataframe with the following schema:

```
df.printSchema()    
root
     |-- word: string (nullable = true)
     |-- vector: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I need to convert this to the following schema:

```
root
 |-- word: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vector: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

I do not want to specify the schema before hand, but instead change the existing one.

I have tried the following

```
df.withColumn("vector", col("vector").cast("array<element: double>"))
```

I have also tried converting it into an RDD to use map to change the elements and then turn it back into a dataframe, but I get the following data type  `Array[WrappedArray]` and I am not sure how to handle it.

Using pyspark and numpy, I could do this by `df.select("vector").rdd.map(lambda x: numpy.asarray(x))`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. Try this code:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("vector", col("vector").cast("array<double>"))
```